# App crashing when trying to set ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, crash, imageview

I'm trying to dynamically add an image to an ImageView on my Android application, but when I'm doing it, my app crash with this message : "MyApp has unfortunately stopped". 
Here is my Java file :

```
public class ScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);

    //Get the ImageView
    ImageView my_image = findViewById(R.id.fond_score);
    //Set the image
    my_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.score_gagne_background);
}}
```

and my xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fond_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My logs write this :

04/21 11:55:19: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p uqac.dim.houla /Users/gregoirethibaud/Documents/Etudes/UQAC/Informatique mobile/Houla-Projet/app/build/intermediates/instant-run-apk/debug/app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "uqac.dim.houla/uqac.dim.houla.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 7244 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@uqac.dim.houla-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/uqac.dim.houla-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa9e8300, tid 7244
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/---: clic
I/---: clic
I/Résultat minijeu :: false
I/MainActivity: Mini-jeu perdu...
                Debut EndGame
I/score: 0
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
       Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 172MB allocation
       Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 1(152KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 364MB/368MB, paused 59us total 5.309ms
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 180633612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 19MB until OOM"
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
       Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 172MB allocation
       Starting a blocking GC Alloc
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 180633612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 19MB until OOM"
D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: uqac.dim.houla, PID: 7244
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 180633612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
                      at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
                      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                      at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
                      at uqac.dim.houla.ScoreActivity.onCreate(ScoreActivity.java:30)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7244 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

I don't understand, my image only weight 250Ko...
Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: `Failed to allocate a 180633612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 19MB until OOM" I/art` REDUCE image size

Comment: It's due to the large image size, which is going out of memory. Bring your image down according to the device size and view size.

Comment: Ok thank you, I reduced the size of my image from 1440x 2560 (250Ko) to 200x356 (79Ko), now it's works, but I would like to display my image in full size (to make a background on my app). Is there maybe an other solution to do it ? Thank you very much !